# Creation post on chatter group

Tags: apex, chatter

I 'm creating a post for a chatter's group.
All works with:

```
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();

post.CreatedById=user.id;

post.ParentId =fgroup.id;
```

But i want that the post is created by the group.

if a write:

```
post.CreatedById=group.id;
```

i get an error.

Do you know other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreatedById is always a user. You can't use a group as the poster. You could use the "Chatter Expert" user or create your own user to use when posting generic messages.